# Initializing kotlin map with nested generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a Kotlin map defined on a Dagger component interface that I'm trying to test by initializing the map with some fake values.
Since the map is defined with nested generics types for value, the compiler complains about initializing incorrectly.

Here's the way the map is declared on the interface-

```
interface ClassInjectionHolder {
  fun classInjections(): Map<Class<out Any>, Provider<ClassInjection<out Any>>>
}
```

Here are the ways I've tried initializing this map-

```
private val injectionMap = mutableMapOf<Class<out Any>, Provider<ClassInjection<out Any>>>()

@Mock private lateinit var mockInjectionProvider1: Provider<ClassInjection<Test1>>
injectionMap.put(Test1::class.java, mockInjectionProvider1) // doesn't work
```

```
private val injectionMap = mapOf<Class<out Any>, Provider<ClassInjection<out Any>>>(Test1::class.java to mockInjectionProvider1)
```

I believe what is happening is that Kotlin cannot detect that `Provider<ClassInjection<Test1>` can be included in a map of `Provider<ClassInjection<out Any>`.
It does compile if the map is declared as-

```
Map<Class<out Any>, Provider<out ClassInjection<out Any>>>
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work well with Dagger.
Any ideas on how to initialize the map without specifying the covariance for ClassInjection?